# How to print a random element from a list on to excel file rows on openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming. I have been trying to print a random element from the following list:

```
senior_duties = ["SOPs", "EQA review", "Doc review", "NC review", "Trend analysis"]
```

I have tried this

```
import random

rand_senior_duties = print(random.choice(senior_duties))
```

Then I assigned rand_senior_duties to the cells like this:

```
sheet["D5"] = rand_senior_duties
```

However it only prints to the console and not the actual sheet.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don’t need print. Replace with `rand_senior_duties = random.choice(senior_duties)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` prints to the console (stdout, "standard out") as you noted, and returns the value `None`.

Consider this:

```py
import random

senior_duties = ["SOPs", "EQA review", "Doc review", "NC review", "Trend analysis"]

rand_senior_duties = print(random.choice(senior_duties))
print(rand_senior_duties)

# sheet["D5"] = rand_senior_duties
```

What get's printed?

```
EQA review
None
```

What's the value of `rand_senior_duties`?  It's just `None`, because that's what `print()` returns.

Let's get rid of the first `print()` statement, and make sure `rand_senior_duties` is getting a random value assigned to it:

```py
...

rand_senior_duties = random.choice(senior_duties)
print(rand_senior_duties)

# sheet["D5"] = rand_senior_duties
```

and now I get:

```
Doc review
```

Now, you can delete the final `print()` statement, and just assign `rand_senior_duties` to `sheet["D5"]`.  If you still want the `print()` to help you understand your program, just have it on a line by itself so that it doesn't interfere with any other value assignments:

```py
...

rand_senior_duties = random.choice(senior_duties)
print(rand_senior_duties)

sheet["D5"] = rand_senior_duties
```